# Can using Selenium WebDriver for automated web crawling be dangerous?

Tags: selenium, security, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to crawl a set of random websites received from a URL generator, using Selenium's [ChromeDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) with [Crawljax](http://crawljax.com/) to do static code analysis on the captured DOM states.

Is this potentially unsafe for the machine doing the crawling?

My concern is that one of the randomly generated sites is malicious and that execution of JavaScript from ChromeDriver (which is used to capture the new DOM states) infects the machine running the test somehow. Should I be running this in some kind of sandboxed environment?

--edit--

If it matters, the crawler is implemented entirely in Java.

Comment: Chrome runs everything in a Sandboxed environment. If you are not installing any chrome add-ons then I don't see it to be a big problem.

But many sites uses tracker and the tracker can trace the common sites you have been browsing. So you can either do a individual profile for every domain. But since you are just crawling and not storing an private cookies, re-using same instance for different domains also should not be a problem

Comment: Thanks a lot @TarunLalwani, it seems like your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, no. Only if your afraid of cookies, and even if you are, your machine isn't.

Comment: so essentially, if using the same instance of ChromeDriver for all sites, any site could potentially leave cookies that informs it of the crawler's activities on other sites, right? If that's the case, yeah that's not so scary. I'd assume also that the cookies are dropped once the instance of ChromeDriver dies, but that's something I'd have to check, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say it's very secure,you should aware of that there is no absolute secure in network.Recently,a chrome RCE has been put out,details:
[SSD Advisory – Chrome Turbofan Remote Code Execution – SecuriTeam Blogs](https://blogs.securiteam.com/index.php/archives/3379)

Maybe this can effect on Selenium's ChromeDriver

But you can do some enforce on your system,such as change your firewall mode to white list,only allow your python script and selenium to access internet on port 80,443.

Even if your system pwned by RCE,the malicious code still can't access internet,unless it inject to you python process(I think it's very hard to do with js script in Browser RCE).

Another option:Install HIPS,if your python script want to do anything else but crawl web page(such as start an other process) or read/write some other files,you will know it and decide what to do.

In my oppion,do your crawl thing in a VM and do some enforce on firewall(Windows firewall or Linux iptables),shutdown useless services in windows.That's enough.

In a word,it's diffcult to find the balance between security and convenience and do not believe your system is unbreakable

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ElizabethAnne. I took a look at the link you posted, and it mentioned, "The following PoC will run calc when attacking a –no-sandbox chrome version 59." Do you think that statement implies that a sandboxed version of Chrome wouldn't be susceptible to such a vulnerability? I'm wondering if running the crawler in a VM and restricting port usage is redundant if using Chrome in sandboxed mode.